# java WEB application - authorization throught domain user

Tags: java, spring, authentication, ldap, authorization

I have a java web application (running on JBoss), which need to authorizate users by their domain objects, without asking any usernames and passwords.
Users are running windows, authorization with LDAP server.
WEB application is based on SPRING, so i hope that there is already implemented same functionality, but i didn't fount it.
Is it possible to authorizate user without asking username and password?
Some links on samples would be great :)

Comment: Found some solutions. Links below:
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0441.html - old sample throught JSP
http://blog.springsource.org/2009/09/28/spring-security-kerberos/ - a bit harder, but more actual sample of spring Kerberos/SPNEGO extention (that's what i was looking for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found some solutions. Links below:

- http://rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0441.html - old sample throught JSP
- http://blog.springsource.org/2009/09/28/spring-security-kerberos - a bit harder, but more actual sample of spring Kerberos/SPNEGO extention (that's what I was looking for).